# What are possible reasons for exception in copy constructors?

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

I've seen in Herb Sutter's book that a copy constructor may throw an exception.

My first question is if a copy constructor may always throw an exception ?

My second question is if a copy constructor which does not use the new operator and other functions inside a copy constructor, is there still a possible exception ?

Comment: If a copy constructor would always throw an exception, it wouldn't copy-construct anything, now would it?

Comment: @DevSolar: I interpreted it as "Are there copy constructors that _never_ throw"?  Which is a question that makes more sense.

Comment: I mean by "a copy constructor always do an exception" there is always some sourse for a possible exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "do an exception" you mean it may throw an exception, then no. Not every copy constructor does. If the class contains only an int, and the copy constructor just copies the int, there is no way it will throw an exception.

Whether an arbitrary copy constructor may throw an exception, is really just a special case of the general question, will any function throw an exception?

As you may expect, it depends entirely on what those other functions it calls does. If any of them use throw or perform some special behaviour that throws an exception, possibly implementation-defined, then it may throw an exception. Otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

Just about any C++ function except destructors and `main` could theoretically throw an exception, depending on what the programmer has written.

Not all copy constructors throw exceptions.  For instance any "Plain Old Data" or "standard layout" structs/classes by default have copy constructors that will never throw.  However, most classes worth talking about contain either a `map` or a `vector` or a `string`, all of which have copy constructors that might throw a `std::bad_alloc`.

```
struct person {
    char name[20];
    int id;
    int height;
};
```

By far, `std::bad_alloc` is the most common exception from a copy constructor, but any exception is possible.  To find out what exceptions copying might throw, you'll have to look at the specifications for the specific class.